# Example of a space group which does not contain the point group as a subgroup

Tags: solid-state-physics, group-theory, crystals

In my current understanding, a space group $G_\infty$ is a combination of a crystallographic point group $G_0$ and translations in the following way: $(R_1,\vec{t_1})(R_2,\vec{t_2}):=(R_1R_2,\vec{t_1}+R_1\vec{t_2})\in G_\infty$. Now I have heard that there are space groups, which do not contain $G_0$ as a subgroup i.e. $\exists R\in G_0:(R,0)\not\in G_\infty$. I would love to see an example. So can anyone make (or provide a link to) an example of such a space group?

Edit: I assume that I misunderstood the person telling me the statement above. Probably he wanted to tell me about the existence of cases like the one illustrated below. So the question properly rephrased should sound like:
Can anyone provide an example of a space group which has an element g, for which the element $gt^-1\not\in G_\infty$ where t is the "translational contribution" to g.

Comment: I think that this definition of space groups is not quite right. Space groups can contain additional symmetries which are combinations of a translation and a rotation/reflection (glide planes, screw axes), where neither the rotation nor the translation involved are elements of the point group.

Comment: This might just be what I am looking for. Could you provide an example of such a group?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the thread [Does the space group P63/m (No. 176) have C6 rotation symmetry?](/q/518965) explores one example of such a group in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is an answer to your question, but per your comment I will leave it anyway. Consider the Kagome lattice, shown below [[ref](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277333917_Structure-dynamics_relation_in_shaken_optical_lattices/figures?lo=1)]. One can see in the image that the Kagome lattice has the same translational symmetries of a triangular lattice: each of the red, blue, and green sublattices form a triangular lattice, connected by the Bravais lattice vectors $\mathbf{b}_1$, $\mathbf{b}_2$, $\mathbf{b}_3$. We also have point group symmetries, which are equivalent to those of the hexagonal honeycomb lattice, which the Kagome is the bond-dual lattice of (place a vertex and the center of each triangle and you will see they form a honeycomb lattice with the vertices of the Kagome lying on the bonds of the honeycomb).

[image]

Notice that the translations $\mathbf{a}_1$, $\mathbf{a}_2$, $\mathbf{a}_3$ are not symmetries of the lattice by themselves, but that we can construct new symmetry operations by combining a translation by $\mathbf{a}_i$ followed by a reflection across the line which that vector lies along. Take the two green arrows on the triangle labeled (1) and translate them by $\mathbf{a}_1$, then reflect them across the horizontal line forming the base of the triangle (1) and you will get the dashed green arrows. This is a glide symmetry, and it cannot be written as a combination of one of the Bravais translations and a point group operation. Neither the translation by $\mathbf{a}_i$ nor the reflection perpendicular to $\mathbf{a}_i$ are elements of either the translation or point symmetry groups of the lattice, but together they are an element of the space symmetry group.

Edit:

Some more info on space groups is available on the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group). Notice that it lists "Symmetry fixing a point" (the point group), then Translations, then Glide and Screw symmetries, which are called non-symmorphic symmetries. They are present in the space group but they are not a simple composition of a translation and point symmetry operation.

For more info on space symmetry groups one may consult the books:

["Group Theory: Application to the Physics of Condensed Matter"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540328971) by Dresselhaus & Dresselhaus

[The mathematical theory of symmetry in solids. Representation theory for point groups and space groups](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1107/S0567739473001476) by C. J. Bradley and A. P. Cracknell

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer!
However, I don't quite understand why the described "glide symmetry" is a symmetry of the lattice. Is it really a symmetry of the lattice in a strict sense? Because to me it appears that after the described operation, blue dots are mapped to blue dots but red dots are mapped to green dots and vice versa. In a "true" symmetry, I would expect the coloured dots to be mapped on the same colour again.

Comment: @Simon the red blue and green are just to help visualize. Clearly the point group includes a C3 rotation which permutes the sublattices, and that is a symmetry. If the red blue and green were distinguishable in some way, we would have broken the lattice symmetry. When we say something is a symmetry of the lattice we treat all lattice points as being equivalent (e.g. color them all black)

Comment: For example, graphene is a honeycomb lattice of identical carbon atoms. It has two sublattices. On the other hand, h-BN is also a honeycomb structure but with different ions on each sublattice, and therefore it has a different space group (it does not have the bond inversion symmetry of graphene)

Comment: Ok, If we assume all colours to represent the same type of dot/atom/whatever, then it's clear now. Thank you!

Comment: @Kai could you supply additional reference to your answer or is the link enough?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I added a few resources with more info, the original link was just the source for the image

Comment: @Kai I was thinking of something specific to Kagome.  I am aware of these to excellent resources and in fact I used Dresselhaus as reference for one of my classes.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero unfortunately I don't have a good reference discussing the Kagome lattice space group specifically. There is extensive literature on the Kagome lattice in the context of frustrated magnetism but I haven't seen any which discuss the space group extensively

Comment: Oh dear... thanks anyways.   Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

For example, a glide reflection $g$ is a combined operation of a reflection plane $\sigma$ and a translation through a certain fraction of one of the basic vectors $\mathbf{a}$ of the lattice, which I denote $\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{a}$. In practice, the translation is always either a fraction $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{4}$ of the magnitude of the basis vectors. A glide symmetry is, therefore, a combination of a ''rotational'' element with a translation operation. There exist space groups that do contain the glide reflection $g = (\sigma \circ \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{a})$, but which do not contain the reflection plane $\sigma$ alone. However, by definition, the point group of a certain space group can be deduced from the spacegroup by:

1. Leave out the translations
2. Convert all symmetry elements that contain translational components (such as glide reflections, but so-called "skew rotations" are the other example) into their respective symmetry element without translation symmetry.
3. Leave all normal point group operations (rotation, roto inversion, and mirror planes).

Rule 2) implies that the glide reflection $g = (\sigma \circ \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{a})$ becomes simply the reflection plane $\sigma$ in the corresponding point group. Therefore, the point group contains a symmetry element that is not an element of the corresponding space group, meaning it is not a subgroup of its space group.

The intuition behind this is that the macroscopic properties of a crystal, which are determined by the symmetry of the point group, should not care about half a translation of the unit cell. Therefore, the "microscopic" fact that the space group has only a glide plane boils results in the point group (which, by definition, cannot contain translations) having the corresponding mirror plane. Conversely, applying the mirror plane to the crystal results in an identical crystal that is shifted by half a unit cell, which is unnoticeable macroscopically.